# Remove Quotation with Access Append query

Tags: sql, ms-access, replace

Currently trying to appending data to a table from a linked monthly updated excel file and continue to get quotation marks showing up when I open the file when I check it. Since formatting, removing errors, etc are not working on the excel file side I thought if there was a way on the access side to fix this. I know the Replace function can remove it if I create a new table but I want to see if I can use this function with an append query. Any help would be appreciated.

Formula when creating new table/works:

```
SELECT Update.ACCTNUMBER, Replace([UNITS],'"','') AS UNIT, Replace([PRICE],'"','') AS PRICES, INTO [New Table]
FROM Update;
```

Append query currently using/want to use replace function with:

```
INSERT INTO Master_Table ( ACCTNUMBER, UNITS, PRICE )
SELECT Update.ACCTNUMBER, Update.UNITS, Update.PRICE
FROM Update;
```

Comment: `Update` is a keyword. Besides that its the very same, you only need to qualify the table name: `SELECT [Update].ACCTNUMBER, Replace([Update].UNITS,'"',''), ...`

Comment: Yes, use Replace() function in append query. SELECT in the append would be same as the stand alone SELECT. Did you not try?